# How to configure both a MySQL and a MongoDB in Spring boot 1.4.3?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I want to set up a MySQL database and a MongoDB in a Spring Boot Project. How to do this? Been searching the web for a few days, but only found how to set up two SQL databases.

All help are appreciated.

Best Regards.

Comment: Use the same example you found.  You only need to change the driverClassName for each driver and include the required libraries

Comment: make sure you add the spring-boot mongodb starter pack to your pom.xml

Comment: Just set URLs for each of them in your properties. They're almost independent and won't require special configuration.

Comment: This is the guide that I tried to follow: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases 
But I seem to miss some essential part. Tried all your suggestions.

Comment: May be this will help 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32820957/in-spring-boot-how-can-we-connect-to-two-databases-mysql-database-and-mongodb